# How to solve Polyspace warning "array index out of bounds"

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, constants

While doing Polyspace analysis on the code base, I am getting an orange check warning on below snippet saying that the pointer may be outside its bounds.

I've tried adding a null check before accessing the array like `if( x[i] != NULL)`, but it doesn't help.  The pointer which is passed as an argument to the function is also declared as a pointer, so that I'm not able to determine the size of buffer being passed to the function.

```
void foo(const int *x, unsigned int value)
{
   int i, data;
   for(i=0;i<value;i++)
   {
      data = x[i]; // pointer may be out of bounds here
   }
   sendToSomeOtherInterface(data);
}
```

I can understand that Polyspace might be assuming that at some point of time, the pointer may point to an invalid memory and code may crash, but how to write code more cleanly to avoid the problem? I can't change usage of pointers as it has an impact over huge files.

Comment: What is `value` then? Doesn't it represent the number of elements to be accessed from `x`?

Comment: Note that null check doesn’t help anything since contents are not pointers and you’re already accessing the element when doing a comparison. Also nulls have no relation to accessing arrays out of bounds. If the analyzer can’t figure out where the pointer comes from and how much data is allocated where it points to it may warn about it even if it weren’t true

Comment: You should check the calling function and a few levels up. Is there a link between the `value` and the size of the array `x`? Is it statically known that `value` will be always less than the size?

Comment: Please show examples of how `x` is allocated.  If using dynamic allocation, polyspace may be picking up on classic programming errors such as `x = malloc(value)` (instead of `value * sizeof(int)`) and then issuing this warning as a result.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje: `value` is dynamic and  coming from another interface, and there is no link between size of the array `x`. We can't assume the the content of  `value` to be static.

Comment: @RakeshMenon How do you ensure that the `value` is always less than the size of the array? You should consider adding a check for this if the two are independently generated variables.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje@paddy `x` is allocated based on user input, when user gives particular input, the row of a 2D array gets assigned to `x`. But I cant limit the value with respect to the table size as it is in another module and if some one adds something into that table, it will create a dependency in this module.

Comment: Would you avoid the warning if you changed `value` to an unsigned type such as `size_t`?  Is the concern that you could be given a negative `value` and your code does not protect against that misuse of the interface?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The `value` is already declared as unsigned in the actual code, for making an example I just typed int. I will edit the question.

Comment: @RakeshMenon I am not sure what is the 2D array here or the table, but in general if you have a user input, you should always sanity check the values. e.g. size is from user and user gives a small number for size. then `x[value-1]` may go out of bounds for the array.

Comment: It's really hard to help when we're not shown the code that generates the error but something vaguely similar.

Answer (score 2):

How Polyspace handles this depends on the context of the analysis.  If you run just that function through on its own, and depend on Polyspace's main generator, then I would expect that to be an orange out of bounds array index on line 6.

A few things to consider:

1. This code breaks at least a few common industry coding guidelines regarding usage of pointers and arrays.
2. In order for Polyspace to know that index `i` is going to be within the bounds of the buffer pointed to by the constant pointer `x`, Polyspace will need to be able to know the size of the buffer represented by `x`.
3. Without any calling context (using main generator and no explicit calls to this function), Polyspace is going to be stuck in the situation of not knowing the bounds of `x` or the value of `value`.  This is true for anyone on stackoverflow just reading the code without context as well.
4. If you analyze the function with calling context, that code may provide enough information.  Ultimately, Polyspace has to be able to see the size of what is passed in via the constant pointer `x`